Blazor client-side Razor components cannot successfully call HttpClient.GetFromJsonAsync in OnInitializedAsync event
I have a .Net 8 blazor solution. On creation I chose an Interactive render mode of "auto", and when visual studio built the solution it created two projects: one server-side, one client-side.
I added a <CascadingAuthenticationState> tag to wrap the entire contents of my Routes.razor file (which Visual Studio put in my server-side application). My Routes.razor looks like this:
    <CascadingAuthenticationState>
<Router AppAssembly="typeof(Program).Assembly" AdditionalAssemblies="new[] { typeof(Client._Imports).Assembly }">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="routeData" DefaultLayout="typeof(Layout.MainLayout)" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
</Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>

The MainLayout.razor was also created in the server-side project, I added an ErrorBoundary but otherwise it is the default:
<main>
    <article class="content px-4">
        <ErrorBoundary>
            <ChildContent>
                @Body
            </ChildContent>
            <ErrorContent Context="exception">
                <Error Exception="@exception" />
            </ErrorContent>
        </ErrorBoundary>
    </article>
</main>


    
I kept the default NavMenu.Razor (also on the server-side) and wrapped all of the menu options in an AuthorizeView tag, it looks like this. The "Home" and "Claims" pages are in the server-side project, and the "Client Payee Search" page is in the client-side project:
        <AuthorizeView Policy="AnyPayeeAdminRole">
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                <span class="bi bi-house-door-fill-nav-menu" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="claims">
                <span class="bi bi-plus-square-fill-nav-menu" aria-hidden="true"></span>Claims
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="ClientPayeeSearch">
                <span class="bi bi-plus-square-fill-nav-menu" aria-hidden="true"></span>Client Payee Search
            </NavLink>
        </div>
    </AuthorizeView>

The link to "ClientPayeeSearch" points to a page in the client-side project. The top of that page has these four statements:
@rendermode InteractiveWebAssembly
@inject HttpClient HttpClient
@inject IConfiguration Configuration
@attribute [Authorize(Policy = "AnyPayeeAdminRole")]

In my server-side Program.cs I have OIDC configuration. We happen to use PingOne, so when I start this web application on my local host I'm immediately shunted to PingOne to enter my username and password, and then redirected back. The PingOne OIDC application type is "Web App". The scopes that get passed are "openid", "profile", "email", "address", "phone". All of this works fine:
        services.AddAuthentication(delegate (AuthenticationOptions authenticationOptions)
    {
        authenticationOptions.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
        authenticationOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = "OpenIdConnect";
    }).AddCookie(delegate (CookieAuthenticationOptions cookieAuthenticationOptions)
    {
        cookieAuthenticationOptions.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied = async delegate
        {
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        };
    }).AddOpenIdConnect(delegate (OpenIdConnectOptions openIdConnectOptions)
    {
        openIdConnectOptions.Authority = ssoAppSettings.PingOne.Authority;
        openIdConnectOptions.CallbackPath = ssoAppSettings.PingOne.CallbackPath;
        openIdConnectOptions.ClientId = ssoAppSettings.PingOne.ClientId;
        openIdConnectOptions.ClientSecret = clientSecret;
        openIdConnectOptions.SignedOutCallbackPath = ssoAppSettings.PingOne.SignedOutCallbackPath;
        openIdConnectOptions.ResponseType = ssoAppSettings.PingOne.ResponseType;
        openIdConnectOptions.SaveTokens = true;
        openIdConnectOptions.Scope.Clear();
        string[] scopes = ssoAppSettings.PingOne.Scopes;
        foreach (string item in scopes)
        {
            openIdConnectOptions.Scope.Add(item);
        }

        openIdConnectOptions.Events.OnAuthenticationFailed = (AuthenticationFailedContext context) => Task.CompletedTask;
        openIdConnectOptions.Events.OnAccessDenied = (AccessDeniedContext context) => Task.CompletedTask;
        openIdConnectOptions.Events.OnRemoteFailure = (RemoteFailureContext context) => Task.CompletedTask;
    });

My problem is, in my client-side page, I cannot fetch a generic list from my server-side web api in the OnInitializedAsync event. The server-side web api is protected with an Authorize attribute and looks like this:
[Authorize(Policy = "AnyPayeeAdminRole")]
public class CacheController : ControllerBase
{

[HttpGet("GetClients")]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<PLP.Library.PayeeAdmin.Models.Client>>> GetClients()
{
    return await _cache.GetClients();
}

I'm calling it from my client-side Razor component like this:
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{

var authState = await 
AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();

    var clients = await HttpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<PLP.Library.PayeeAdmin.Models.Client>>("api/cache/GetClients");

The call to GetAuthenticationStateAsync() returns an AuthenticationState with a User object that shows I am authenticated. IsAuthenticated is true, and it has my Identity with all of the claims that were added server-side. Apparently what I am missing is how to pass this authentication information to my HttpClient.GetFromAsync method.
The call to GetFromJasonAsync never reaches the method. Instead, the controller tries to redirect me back to PingOne to get my credentials; it returns a blob of html attempting to do that. Since that is not a generic list my call fails.
What am I missing? In my client-side project, in my program.cs, I am adding the "HttpClient" like so:
            builder.Services.AddScoped(o => new HttpClient
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress)
        });

Do I need to add something else to the HttpClient? Or do I need to add some argument to my HttpClient.GetFromJsonAsync call?
Part of the attraction of Blazor was me assuming it handled all of the authorization using attributes, but that is not working out so well!

The relevant server-side Web API is protected by the Authorize attribute, so you need to add the corresponding authentication credentials when accessing it. If you use tokens or cookies for authentication, you need to include these authentication credentials in the request. In your code, cookie authentication and Policy = "AnyPayeeAdminRole" are set, so you need to add these authentication cookies and include the relevant role information in the request to access it.

@YuningDuan thanks, that makes sense, but do you have any idea how to do that? How to add the authentication cookie to an HttpGet request? The documentation is opaque at best.

You can use js to get the cookie, then add it to the httpclient request header, and get the cookie from the api. Here is an example for your reference:
First, there is a cookie in my browser with the value of John Doe.

I created a JS method to get the cookie.
window.cookieHelper = {
    getCookie: function (name) {
        let cookies = document.cookie.split('; ');
        for (let cookie of cookies) {
            let [key, value] = cookie.split('=');
            if (key === name) {
                return value;
            }
        }
        return null;
    },
}

In my component, I call the js method through a button and add the cookie to the request header.
@page "/fetchdata"
@using System.Net
@using System.Net.Http
@using System.Net.Http.Json
@inject IJSRuntime JS 
@inject HttpClient Http
@rendermode InteractiveWebAssembly

<button @onclick="FetchWeatherForecast">Fetch Weather Forecast</button>
@code {

    private async Task FetchWeatherForecast()
    {

        var cookieValue = await JS.InvokeAsync<string>("cookieHelper.getCookie", "Cookie");

        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cookies",cookieValue);

        var response = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>("https://localhost:7295/WeatherForecast");

    }
}

In the API, I capture it through HttpContext.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Cookies"):
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
{

    if (HttpContext.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Cookies"))
    {
        var success = HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Cookies", out var headervalue);

        if (success)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation(headervalue.ToString());
        }
    }
    return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
    {
        Date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
        TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
        Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
    })
    .ToArray();
}

There can observe that the cookie value has been successfully captured:

Note that you need to change the request url to your target URL in your project.

Thanks @Yuning-duan, for now I'm switching to blazor server, but if I get a chance to return to this I will try your solution to see if it works with the authentication cookie, and see if it passes or fails a vulnerability test.
